# Tabspec buttons is not clickable when run on latest APIs

Tags: android, android-tabs

I've an application with tab spec contains 3 tabs, each tab has multiple buttons, it is running properly with android version 2.3.6 (Ginger Bread), but when i run it on API over 17 the buttons in the tabs are not clickable !!

what would be the cause of this problem , i really need your help!! 
thanks